# uncompress data from tcp socket

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, zlib

I can connect to server, by using putty. I add ip address and port number, and then I connect.
Before data starts to flow, I need to type "USERNAME=mysusername,PASSWORD=mypassword"
When I do this, data starts to flow... I can see it, but it is compressed.
I need to uncompress this data.

Format is this: Header+PayLoad

I need to process the header, and convert it, and uncompress it, and later on, I will insert this data to mysql.

I would like to know, how this is done with PHP, or if there is better solution ie C, C++.
I am connecting using windows, with mysql and php installed.
Data is continious, and somehow, I think, needs to store data first on a file, and then run a script lets say every minute, and restart...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in my experience dealing with this kind of data is easier in C, it can be done in php, using the [php socket API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).  There are some easy examples on the [examples page](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php), including a simple socket client.

To decode the binary data read from the socket you can use the [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function.

Why do you think this needs to be done in two stages?  Normally reading, parsing, decoding and storing the data in the database shouldn't take too long.

Comment: @Ossi binding means server side and you cannot bind a server on your machine to serve some socket elsewhere of course.  So I suspect you started from the **server** democode and not the **client** democode.  However, it's not a good idea to sort of extend the question via the comments, I'd suggest you try again using the client democode and if questions arise, just open a new question here on SO.

Comment: I think Im little confused, how these sockets supposed to work. I have tried first example, and if I understand correctly, I put 127.0.0.1 and port 1234 on example.php . Then I use putty to connect to external ip and port 1234, and I should see same result on my browser echoed from my Putty screen correct? Confused

Comment: Funny how we typed at the same time, after I did delete my first comment... I will accept this and ask new questions... Thanks for getting me in the right direction.